# Interesting Java List Contains Query

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I know about the Java containsAll method but this method does not do the trick for my requirement. Suppose I have a list A

```
[7 1 0 4 5]
```

and another list B

```
[1 1]
```

When I use A.containsAll(B) I get true but I want it to be false because 2 ones are not in the list A.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: `Java !== JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

CollectionUtils from apache framework is handy. [isSubCollection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isSubCollection(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) method does the trick here and solves your purpose.

```
public static boolean isSubCollection(Collection<?> a,
                      Collection<?> b)
```

See Below what the description reads-

> Returns true iff a is a sub-collection of b, that is, iff the
>   cardinality of e in a is less than or equal to the cardinality of e in
>   b, for each element e in a. Parameters: a - the first (sub?)
>   collection, must not be null b - the second (super?) collection, must
>   not be null Returns: true iff a is a sub-collection of b

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a "direct" way to do this (by only calling a single "checking" method such as `contains()`).

As the other answer points out; there might be 3rd party library methods that allow for such kind of checks.

If that is not an option, there are various ways how you can implement such a check yourself. For example:

- create a class that represents `ListItem<T>`. This class basically contains *one* element from a list of an arbitrary type (in your example it would be `ListItem<Integer>` - and the number of occurrences of that item within a specific list.
- then you create ListItem objects for both your lists
- and when you then implement equals/hashCode correctly for ListItem, you can create a List of ListItems - and then ask if another ListItem is contained.

In your example:

```
 A: [7 1 0 4 5] gives ListItems (0, 1) (1, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (7,1)
```

and

```
 B: [ 1 1 ]     gives ListItem (1, 2)
```

And obviously the ListItem(1,2) for B is not a showing up in the list of ListItems for list A.

You don't necessarily create a specific class for that, a simple `HashMap<T, Integer>` would do, but having a distinct class would allow for nice helper methods, like implicit increase of the counter values.

Another alternative that requires overhead of a different nature: first sort both lists, and then iterate the first list and check if each entry of the second list shows up.